# Plural form of abbreviation ending with "s"

Tags: grammatical-number, abbreviations

I am wondering how can We pluralize the abbreviation "TS" (Training Sequence)? Is it " TSes" or "TS's", I think It can't be "TSs"

Comment: Why do you think it can't be TSs?

Comment: I just think how can We pronoun it as /ti: es es/ if it's "TSs"

Comment: Just pronounce it /ti es ez. You would pronounce it that way regardless how you write it.

Answer (score 1):

Totally wrong: you've chosen the  obsoleted versions, and dismissed the modern one:-)

In

> 7.14 Plurals for letters, abbreviations, and numerals
>
> Capital letters used as words, numerals used as nouns, and
>   abbreviations usually form the plural by adding s.
>
> the three Rs
>
> IRAs
>
> URLs
>
> BSs, MAs, PhDs
>
> [**CMOS (Chicago Manual of Style)**](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org)